# Trigger com soma entre datas

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, trigger

Boa Noite, Preciso de uma ajuda que não estou conseguindo, Tenho duas tabelas em meu db.

1 - Tabela carteira composta por:

```html
CREATE TABLE `carteira` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `datat` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `vl_cliente` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `carteira` (`id`, `datat`, `vl_cliente`) VALUES
(1, '2018-05-01 06:19:18', '50.00'),
(2, '2018-05-01 11:05:15', '100.00'),
(3, '2018-05-02 02:24:07', '20.00'),
(4, '2018-05-02 03:11:00', '80.00'),
(5, '2018-05-02 10:29:43', '1.00'),
(6, '2018-05-03 08:27:42', '500.00'),
(7, '2018-05-04 02:16:20', '100.00'),
(8, '2018-05-04 05:19:29', '3.50'),
(9, '2018-05-05 08:21:07', '10.00'),
(10, '2018-05-06 08:27:39', '123.00'),
(11, '2018-05-06 10:30:26', '21.00'),
(12, '2018-05-06 10:32:00', '800.00'),
(13, '2018-05-06 11:16:43', '900.00'),
(14, '2018-05-06 15:29:16', '50.00'),
(15, '2018-05-05 18:15:00', '80.00');
```

2 - Tabela Consolidado composta por:

```php
CREATE TABLE `consolidado` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `datat` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `vl_cliente` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `consolidado` (`id`, `datat`, `vl_cliente`) VALUES
(1, '2018-05-01', NULL),
(2, '2018-05-02', NULL),
(3, '2018-05-03', NULL),
(4, '2018-05-04', NULL),
(5, '2018-05-05', NULL),
(6, '2018-05-06', NULL);
```

Estou tentando fazer um **trigger** onde toda vez que fosse **INSERT, UPDATE e DELETE.**

Somasse o valor e INSERT ou UPDATE na tabela consolidado, mais o problema é que alem da soma tem que ser feito a **formatação e agrupamento por data**

Ex. de resultado final:

```
2018-05-01 150,00
2018-05-02 101,00
2018-05-03 500,00
2018-05-04 103,50
2018-05-05 90,00
2018-05-06 1894,0
```

Estou parado com essa trigger:

```html
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `consolida` AFTER INSERT ON `carteira` FOR EACH ROW UPDATE consolidado a
   SET a.vl_cliente = 
    (SELECT SUM(vl_cliente) 
       FROM carteira
      WHERE datat = a.datat)
 WHERE a.datat = NEW.date_format(datat, '%Y-%m-%d')
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Preciso de uma ajuda para resolver esse problema, desde já agradeço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tabela de valores consolidados pode usar a data da consolidação dos valores como sua chave primária, veja só:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_carteira
(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  datat DATETIME,
  vl_cliente NUMERIC(10,2)
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_consolidado
(
  datat DATE PRIMARY KEY,
  vl_total DECIMAL(10,2)
);
```

Infelizmente, no `MySQL` você precisa criar uma *trigger* específica para cada tipo de operação de `INSERT`, `UPDATE` e `DELETE`. Para evitar a replicação do mesmo código nessas *triggers*, a dica é criar uma *stored procedure* única que seria chamada por todas essas *triggers*.

A *stored procedure* precisa ser capaz de identificar se o registro de valores consolidados já existe, isso vai determinar se o registro deve ser incluido ou somente atualizado:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE fc_consolidar_carteira( fdatat DATE )
BEGIN
  IF (SELECT 1 = 1 FROM tbl_consolidado WHERE datat = fdatat ) THEN
  BEGIN
    UPDATE
        tbl_consolidado
    SET
      vl_total = (SELECT sum(c.vl_cliente)
                  FROM tbl_carteira AS c
                  WHERE CAST( c.datat AS DATE ) = fdatat )
    WHERE
        datat = fdatat;
  END;
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_consolidado ( datat, vl_total ) ( SELECT fdatat, c.vl_cliente
                                                      FROM tbl_carteira AS c
                                                      WHERE CAST( c.datat AS DATE ) = fdatat);
  END;
  END IF;
END;
```

E as *triggers* de `INSERT`, `DELETE` e `UPDATE`, respectivamente:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_ai_consolida AFTER INSERT ON tbl_carteira FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  CALL fc_consolidar_carteira( CAST( NEW.datat AS DATE ) );
END;

CREATE TRIGGER trg_ad_consolida AFTER DELETE ON tbl_carteira FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  CALL fc_consolidar_carteira( CAST( OLD.datat AS DATE ) );
END;

CREATE TRIGGER trg_au_consolida AFTER UPDATE ON tbl_carteira FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  CALL fc_consolidar_carteira( CAST( NEW.datat AS DATE ) );
END;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7fc4e/1

Comment: Amigo, muito obrigado pela ajuda, mais nessas trigger ela não está editando a data para o formato Y-m-d

Comment: Entendi! Agora está corrigido! A invés de converter o `DATETIME` para uma string formatada, você pode fazer um `CAST` de `DATETIME` para `DATE`.

Comment: Show! muito obrigado parceiro!